# How to keep array value in react with or without maintaining state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, use-state

I am working on a project where i need to click photos using camera and select a picker value from picker in **upload screen** and send these values to **Display screen**.

what is happening right now in display screen i created an object like below:

```
let myObj = [
    {  Locations:[] },
    { Cars:[] },
    { Space:[] },
    { Technology:[] },
    { Flowers:[] },

]
```

in this Object Locations ,Cars etc are the keys and also the Picker values in upload screen

I select the image from **upload screen** and send data in **display screen** and set in the array in one of the keys in myObj matching values in picker but when i repeat this step second time the array gets empty. I want to keep the value of that array inact so that i can push more values to the array .**For example i select the image and in pikcer i select pikcer value ( e.g Location) now i want to push data of picker(Location) into location object but everytime i go to upload screen array gets empty. I cant fill it** Sorry for bad english

This is my Uplaod Screen:

```
import React, { Fragment, Component, useState,useEffect } from 'react'
import { launchCamera, launchImageLibrary } from "react-native-image-picker"
import { PermissionsAndroid, Pressable, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native'
import { Header, LearnMoreLinks, Colors, DebugInstructons, ReloadInstructions } from 'react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen'
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native-gesture-handler'
import { Picker } from '@react-native-picker/picker';


const Upload = ({navigation}) => {

    const [galleryData, setgallery] = useState({})
    
    const [fileUri, setfileUri] = useState({})
    const [Category, setCategory] = useState("")

    useEffect(()=>{
        setfileUri(
            prev => ({
                ...prev ,newCategory:Category
            })
        )
    },[Category])


    const onPressHandler = ()=>{

        console.log("this one Picked from picker >>>",Category)

        console.log("This one is sent to anoher screen >>>",fileUri["newCategory"])

        navigation.navigate("Display",{MyData:fileUri})

        
        // setfileUri({})
        // setCategory(null)
        
    }


    let options = {
        storageOptions: {
            skipBackup: true,
            path: 'images',
        },
    };

    const requestCameraPermission = async () => {
        try {
            const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
                PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.CAMERA, {
                title: "App Camera Permission",
                message: "App needs access to your camera ",
                buttonNeutral: "Ask Me Later",
                buttonNegative: "Cancel",
                buttonPositive: "OK"

            }
            )
            if (granted == PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
                launchCamera(options, (response) => {
                    console.log("Camera launched")

                    if (response.didCancel) {
                        console.log("Cancelled By User")
                    } else if (response.error) {
                        console.log("Image error")
                    } else if (response.customButton) {
                        alert(response.customButton)
                    } else {
                        // const source = { setfileUri(prev =>({...prev,["data"]})): response.uri }
                        setfileUri(
                            prev => ({
                                ...prev, "data": response["assets"]
                            })
                            // ...fileUri,...response
                        )
                        
                    }

                })
            }
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
    }

    const libraryPicker = async () => {
        try {
            const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
                PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.CAMERA, {

                title: "App Camera Permission",
                message: "App needs access to your camera ",
                buttonNeutral: "Ask Me Later",
                buttonNegative: "Cancel",
                buttonPositive: "OK"

            }
            )
            if (granted == PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
                launchImageLibrary(options, (response) => {
                    console.log("Camera launched")

                    if (response.didCancel) {
                        console.log("Cancelled By User")
                    } else if (response.error) {
                        console.log("Image error")
                    } else if (response.customButton) {
                        alert(response.customButton)
                    } else {
                        // const source = { setfileUri: response.uri }

                        console.log(JSON.stringify(response))
                    }

                })
            }
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
    }
    
    return (
        <View style={styles.body}>

            <View >
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={requestCameraPermission} style={styles.btnSection}>
                    <Text style={styles.text}>
                        Choose File
                    </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>


            <View >
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={libraryPicker} style={styles.btnSection}>
                    <Text style={styles.text}>
                        choose from Gallery
                    </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>

            <View>
                <Picker
                    selectedValue={Category}
                    onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) =>
                        setCategory(itemValue)
                    }
                    style={styles.pickerSection}
                    dropdownIconColor={"#000"}
                    
                >
                    <Picker.Item label='Flowers' value="Flowers" ></Picker.Item>
                    <Picker.Item label='Cars' value="Cars" ></Picker.Item>
                    <Picker.Item label='Space' value="Space" ></Picker.Item>
                    <Picker.Item label='Technology' value="Technology" ></Picker.Item>
                    <Picker.Item label='Locations' value="Locations" ></Picker.Item>

                </Picker>

            </View>

            <View>
                <Pressable
                onPress={onPressHandler}
                style={[({presses}) => ({backgroundColor:presses ? "Red":"grey"}),styles.btnSection]}>
                    <Text style={styles.text}>
                        Press me 
                    </Text>

                </Pressable>

            </View>


        </View>

    )
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    body: {
        flexDirection: "column",
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center"

    },
    text: {
        color: "red",
        fontSize: 14,
        fontWeight: "bold"
    },
    btnSection: {
        width: 200,
        height: 100,
        backgroundColor: "#DCDCDC",
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
        borderRadius: 50,
        margin: 20

    },
    pickerSection:{
        width:200,
        height:100,
        backgroundColor:"red",
        justifyContent:"center",
        alignItems:"center",
        borderRadius:50,
        margin:20
    },
    uploadButton:{
        width: 200,
        height: 100,
        textAlign:"center",
        alignItems:"center",
        borderRadius:50
    }

})

export default Upload
```

This is my Display Screen:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { Image, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native'

const Display = ({navigation,route}) => {

    const data = route.params;
    const Data = data["MyData"]["data"]

    const Category = data["MyData"]["newCategory"]
    console.log(Data,Category)

    //now what we have to do we need to create an object and for values we will use [] to keep on adding data if there is new data added

    let myObj = [
        {  Locations:[] },
        { Cars:[] },
        { Space:[] },
        { Technology:[] },
        { Flowers:[] },

    ]

    for (let i = 0;i<myObj.length;i++){
        console.log(">>",Object.keys( myObj[i])[0])

        if ( Object.keys( myObj[i])[0]===Category){
            myObj[i][Category].push(Data[0].uri)
        }
    }


    console.log(state)    

    return (
        <View>
            {/* <Image 
            source={{uri:Data[0].uri}}
            style={{ width: 500, height: 500 }}
            ></Image> */}


            <Text>okk</Text>
        </View>
    )
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({})

export default Display
```

my App.js

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 *
 * @format
 * @flow strict-local
 */
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native'
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import Upload from './screens/Upload';
import Display from './screens/Display';

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();


const App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
    <Drawer.Navigator
    
    initialRouteName='Upload'
    screenOptions={{
      drawerStyle:{
        backgroundColor:"#D8BFD8",
      },
      drawerActiveBackgroundColor:"#ffffff",
      drawerActiveTintColor:"red",
      swipeEdgeWidth:300,
      drawerHideStatusBarOnOpen:true,
      headerShown:true,
      headerTitleAlign:"center",
      headerStyle:{
        backgroundColor:"#0080ff"
      },
      headerTintColor:"white",
      headerTitleStyle:{
        fontSize:25,
        fontWeight:"bold"
      }

    }}
    >
      <Drawer.Screen name="Upload" component={Upload}
      options={{
        title:"Upload Images"
      }}
      
      />
      <Drawer.Screen name="Display" component={Display}
      options={{
        title:"View Images"
      }}
      
      />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({})

export default App
```

Comment: It's not clear which part of your components is being updated that you have an issue with. I'm guessing it's either the `fileUri` state in `Upload` or the `myObj` object in `Display` that is reset each time that these components remounts. Can you walk us through the code and reproduction steps for the issue?

Comment: Yeah sure. I go to upload screen . Select image and then select picker value from picker and then set them to setfiluri and then send it to display screen . In display screen i created object and its keys are same as of the picker values. So once i match the picker value i push the data of that selected picker value into matched object. For example i select space in picker and in myObj in space key i will push the data .This pushes the data but when i go back to upload screen again to push more data array of space(example only) gets empty

Comment: Right, ok, so my suspicion was correct. Each time to navigate to the upload component it is mounting with initial state. For this you should [lift state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) to a common ancestor component that remains mounted. The [React Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) can help here so you won't need to explicitly pass the state as props to these components. If you have a lot of "shared state" then you may want to consider Redux. You basically just need to persist the `fileUri` state *somewhere* so you can reference it again.

Comment: How to use context api in react -native any example? i have updated my question and also posted my app.js where i have used drawer navigator. Please guide

Comment: The docs I linked. The official React docs are pretty good at that.  It doesn't matter if you are using React-Native, it's the React part that is effectively the same. Create a context, and context provider and provide the `fileUri` state and setter/callback as values, and use the `useContext` React hook to access.